# Como obtener lo valores de acuerdo a su contexto?

Tags: javascript

Quiero obtener los valores de fullname 'name1','name2','name3', de acuerdo al contexto que se encuentra. me serviria usar las funciones bind, call o apply.

```js
var fullname = 'name1';

var person = {
  last: {
    fullname: 'name3',
  },
  fullname: 'name2',
  getFullname: function() {
    return this.fullname
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### La única diferencia entre los métodos, [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/call), [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply), y [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) es en la invocación.

El método [call(](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/call)) llama a una función con un valor **this** asignado y **argumentos** provistos de forma individual.

```
person.getFullname.call(); // 'name2'
person.getFullname.call(this); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.call(person); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.call(person.last); // 'name3'
person.getFullname.call({ fullname: 'hola' }); // 'hola'
```

El método [apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/apply) invoca una determinada función asignando explícitamente el objeto **this** y un array o objeto como **argumentos** para dicha función.

```
person.getFullname.apply(); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.apply(this); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.apply(person); // 'name2'
person.getFullname.apply(person.last); // 'name3'
person.getFullname.apply({ fullname: 'hola' }); // 'hola'
```

El método [bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/bind) crea una nueva función, que cuando es llamada, asigna a su operador  **this** el valor entregado, con una secuencia de **argumentos** dados precediendo a cualquiera entregados cuando la función es llamada.

```
person.getFullname.bind()(); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.bind(this)(); // 'name1'
person.getFullname.bind(person)(); // 'name2'
person.getFullname.bind(person.last)(); // 'name3'
person.getFullname.bind({ fullname: 'hola' })(); // 'hola'
```

> Fuente: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/

Answer (score 1):

Seguramente hay mas formas de obtener algún valor pero estas creo que son las más significativas:

```
// name1
console.log( fullname );

// name2
console.log( person.getFullname() );
console.log( person.fullname );

// name 3
console.log( person.last.fullname );
console.log( person.getFullname.call( person.last ) );
console.log( person.getFullname.apply( person.last ) );

let getName3 = person.getFullname.bind( person.last );
console.log( getName3() );
```

Las funciones `call`, `apply` y `bind` te pueden servir para obtener los valores usando la función `getFullname` pasando objetos que tienen la misma subestructura que `person`, en este caso objetos que tengan una propiedad llamada `fullname`.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no se si te puede ayudar,

```
var fullname = 'name1';

var person = {
  last: {
    fullname: 'name3',
  },
  fullname: 'name2',
  getFullname: function() {
    return fullname + " " + this.fullname + " "  +  this.last.fullname
  }
}

console.log(person.getFullname())
```

Comment: tu respuesta quedaria a medias, porque solo ejemplificas un contexto

Comment: Revisar [answer]